# why the extra \ symbol in this nested scope example?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and came across this great tut:

http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

The 1st example under heading "Nested scope" text generates text to draw a mountain:

What I don't understand is why, on line 11 there is a "\" 
when it only generates one "\"

Please make your explanation suited for dummies - i took a lesson on hoisting and followed this code many times through a debugger before I understood it! :)

Thanks!

Comment: it needs to escape the backslash

Answer (score 3):

Backslashes "escape" characters in a lot of languages. By "escape", I mean they strip them from their special meaning, leaving them a plain character. So when you want a plain backslash, you'll have to escape it to restrain it from escaping something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is the block of code that the question is about:

```
var mountain = function(size) {
    result += "/";
    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++)
      result += "'";
    result += "\\";
  };

// mountain(4); outputs -> /''''\
```

In JavaScript the symbol `\` is used to escape special characters inside strings (like line breaks `\n`).

So, when creating only a single `\`, you must escape *out* of the *escape*.

Thus the double in `result += "\\";`.

Comment: Aaaah thanks! :) And what if I wanted to print two of them (\\)? - which I already tried out of curiosity and got an error...

Comment: Then \\\\ that will escape 2.

Comment: Thanks!  This was my first question on stackoverflow and it got down voted 6 times :/  It would be great if someone could give me any tips as to what I did wrong...